# How to route LAN traffic for OpenVPN?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, openvpn

[Network Environment Setup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tI6b.png)

Speedtest.net without OpenVPN - 300Mbps
Speedtest.net with OpenVPN - 10Mbps
Accessing \\192.168.0.223 through Windows Explorer with OpenVPN - 80-100MB/s

Is accessing \\192.168.0.223 encrypted? If not, how do I encrypt the connection?

OpenVPN Server configuration

```
port 443
proto tcp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

iptables start-up script

```
iptables -t filter -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.10
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s "10.8.0.0/24" -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "10.8.0.0/24" -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Where do you access `\\192.168.0.223` from?

Comment: Remotely (e.g. Public WiFi) after connecting to OpenVPN server hosted on Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access the NAS at all, the access is encrypted. Otherwise the traffic couldn't get routed to the NAS.

The configuration looks also correct.

You can also make sure that the configuration works correctly by using `traceroute -n 192.168.0.223` (*nix) or `tracert -d 192.168.0.223` (Windows) from your remote host and seeing the hops traffic takes.

Comment: Tracing route to 192.168.1.138 over a maximum of 30 hops
  1   255 ms   248 ms    59 ms  **10.8.0.1**
  2   409 ms   248 ms   127 ms  **192.168.0.223**
Trace complete.

Comment: Yes, 10.8.0.1 is the default gateway used in default OpenVPN configurations, so the traffic is encrypted.